# Make multiple hover and click scalable

Tags: html, css

This works correctly for hover, but I am after two other things:

1) a more scalable, generalized solution: every time I add a link and paired paragraph I don't want to have to also include specific CSS for each addition. It seems like I should be able to create the same behavior for each paired link and paragraph generally and apply it to all of the pairs. What I have seems very inefficient.

2) I'd like to also create the same behavior as the hover, but for a click and make it scalable and generalized (as #1 above). The desired behavior is click on link -> paired paragraph appears, click on link again -> paired paragraph disappears again (or something very similar).

Note: I want both click and hover because hover will work for a desktop, but not mobiles. If someone is on a smart phone they can use the click. I'd like solutions to be responsive, to avoid jQuery, and to use CSS only if possible.

Here is what I have now (using only two pairs links and paragraphs, for simplicity):

Markup:

```
<a id="a-1">link1</a>
<p id="p-1">para1</p>
<a id="a-2">link2</a>
<p id="p-2">para2</p>
```

CSS:

```
#a-1,#a-2{
    display: block;
}
#p-1,#p-2{
    display: none;
}

#a-1:hover ~ #p-1 ,#a-2:hover ~ #p-2{
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CzpZ6/

Comment: Have you tried to use a `class` for the elements and work out the `CSS` around them instead? http://jsfiddle.net/CzpZ6/6/

Comment: Yes, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Check the jsFiddle link in my comment. It works for me?

Comment: I see the "+" is the trick. Thanks! What about the click behavior I discuss?

Comment: Can't be achieved without Javascript.

Comment: You shouldn't bother with mobile. Most mobile simulates hover when you tap it.

Comment: Does it have to be an `a` anchor link? Technically, since it doesn't go anywhere a link is not recommended, a button type thing would be better.

Comment: enapupe - I am new to html etc., I read a lot of stuff about "hover is dead" out there because it doesn't work for mobile. I guess that was old. I'll look for some other documentation on what you say... Thanks for the info.

Comment: Paulie_D - it's actually a heading wrapped in a link like: <a><h2>heading text here</h2></a>   I do that for SEO. Search engines like the headings I guess. The link (if I recall) has to be there because it is linked to my nav buttons, but I'll need to take another look at that. I can't remember how it works. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your generalized solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vA32/

```
a{
    display: block;
}
p{
    display: none;
}

a:hover + p {
    display: block;
}
```

If you use plus that will select all the p values until it finds another element. So in this case + can work.

For mobile part you can use this:

```
/* #### Desktops #### */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
  /* some CSS here */
    a{
       display: block;
    }
    p{
      display: none;
    }


    a:hover + p {
       display: block;
    }

}


@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) 
{ 
    a{
       display: block;
    }
    p{
        display: none;
    }

    a:active + p {
        display: block;
    }


}
```

On desktop part it will trigger hover, on mobile part it will trigger click.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8vA32/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:target` attribute, in conjunction with specific IDs (see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CzpZ6/12/))

## HTML

```
<a class="focus" href="#p1">

    Click me or hover me

</a>
<p id="p1">I'm hidden</p>
<a class="focus" href="#p2">

    Click me or hover me

</a>
<p id="p2">I'm another hidden paragraph</p>
```

## CSS

```
.focus {
    display: block;
}
.focus:focus, .focus:hover {
    background-color: pink;
}

.focus + p {
    display: none;
}
.focus:hover + p, p:target {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `:hover` it stops working. Apparently `:focus` and `:hover` behave on the same way. http://jsfiddle.net/CzpZ6/13/

Comment: But why would you remove the `:hover` ? The OP asked for hovering and clicking.

Comment: In the end, the `:focus` isn't doing anything. That's why. What you see that's happening is a result of the `:hover`, even if you're clicking the link.

Comment: You're right, I tested it in Chrome and it's not working. Please see my new answer

Comment: Eliot Berriot - The click behavior isn't exactly what I am looking for, but I think is usable since clicking on another one hides the previous one that was clicked on. MelanciaUK - I'm new to this. Do you see any issues with Eliot Berriot's new answer? I removed the hover and it still works on click.

Comment: @Eliot you should comment the hover part of the css rule in your demo so people can see the click working. just an idea

Answer (score 0):

I believe a jQuery solution is your ONLY solution. For both hover and touch events to work you will need to turn off click and bind touch.  here is a piece of script I use in a Nav menu for tablet size when users may be using either touch or mouse.  Perhaps if you know js you can modify this script to fit your need:

```
function medMenu() {
            //reset the menu in case it's being resized from a small screen
            // unbind click events    
            jQuery('.menuToggle a').off('click');
            jQuery('.topMenu h3').off('click');
            // remove any expanded menus
            jQuery('.expand').removeClass('expand');
            // remove the span tags inside the menu
            jQuery('.topMenu h3').find('span.indicator').remove();
            // remove the "menu" element
            jQuery('.menuToggle').remove();

            //check to see if the device supports touch
            //we'll use touch events instead of click as it will allow us
            //to support both a CSS-driven hover and touch enabled
            //menu for this screen range
            if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)
            {
                //find all 'hover' class and strip them
                 jQuery('.topMenu').find('li.hover').removeClass('hover');
                 //add touch events to submenu headings
                 jQuery(".topMenu h3").bind('touchstart', function(e){
                    //find the current submenu
                    var currentItem = $(this).siblings('.submenu');
                    //remove the expand class from other submenus to close any currently open submenus
                    jQuery('ul.submenu').not(currentItem).removeClass('expand');
                    //open the selected submenu
                    $(this).siblings('.submenu').toggleClass('expand');
                });
                //close submenus if users click outside the menu
                jQuery('html').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
                    jQuery('.topMenu').find('ul.submenu').removeClass('expand');
                });
                //stop clicks on the menu from bubbling up
                jQuery('#mainNav').bind('touchstart', function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
               });
            }
            //indicate current window state
            windowState = 'medium';
        }
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want Javascript or jQuery involved. This would be a nice tip, but not an answer.

Comment: I know he doesn't and I said as much in my answer.  I made it clear that this is an alternative.  Also, I believe a js solution is his ONLY solution.  you are wrong to vote this down.

Comment: It's not the only solution. As you mentioned it, you can achieve this using `:target` selector.

Comment: Yes, for click, but I believe the OP is looking for Touch behavior and is assuming that a touch event is equivalent to a click event, it's not.

Comment: You're right, click and touch are actually different (removed my downvote)

Answer (score -1):

Change out the `id` tag for a generic class

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CzpZ6/5/)

**HTML**

```
<a class="a1">link1</a>
<p>para1</p>
<a class="a1">link1</a>
<p>para2</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.a1 {
    display: block;
}
p {
    display: none;
}


.a1:hover + p, /* the first p after an .a1 anchor */
.a1:focus + p  { 
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The "+" makes all the difference! Thx! What about the click behavior?

Comment: Clicks are achieved with javascript. There is no click function in CSS.

Comment: :active is not quite the same as click()?

Comment: `:active` would work as a first, but as you are clicking a link, it will hide the `p` immediately.

Comment: Depends on what the click event is supposed to do?

Comment: Yeah, `:active` is toggled on mousedown only.

Comment: what about `:target`? that's like  click behavior for css

Comment: This demo is not working for me. @ChrisM is right about `:target`, please give my answer below a try.